# pass through/duplicate arguments in delegated method

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a very simple class with a `#call` method. `#call` needs a hash, the assembly of which I've delegated to another method to keep concerns separate.

This results, however, in a sort of pass-though situation where `#call` accepts an argument that it passes along to the hash assembling method. This feels wrong for two reasons: 1) `#call` and `#params` have identical method signatures and 2) `#call` accepts an argument it doesn't directly use. Though I can't thing of a specific rule/best practice this violates off the top of my head.

```
class Foo

  def initialize(init_var)
    @init_var = init_var
  end

  def call(call_var)
    Bar.do_stuff(params(call_var))
  end

  private

  attr_reader :init_var

  def params(call_var)
    {
      static: 'static',
      init_var: init_var,
      call_var: call_var
    }
  end
end
```

What I'd like to know is:

1) is this actually a code smell or am I being paranoid?
2) if not, is there a situation where it might start to be one?
3) if it is, how might I refactor it?

Comment: why not `Bar.do_stuff(params.merge(call_var: call_var))` and then remove call_var from params method. This removed the duplicated signature while maintaining the same functionality.

Comment: In one way I like that better. `params` is a bareword which feels clean. In another, it seems worse. Suddenly `#params`, whose job it is to build a params hash, is not completely doing its job.

Comment: then call it `default_params` this way it is doing it's job by supply the default values with the assumption modifications will be made.